# Ajax request submitting input multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have table rows that creates a sidebar with input fields through an ajax get request when pressed on a row. The sidebar will in turn have another ajax post request that submits the input fields in the sidebar.

The problem I'm having is that if the user presses around on different table rows and then submits the input fields, it will run the ajax calls for all the table rows that have been pressed but it should only submit for the row that it's currently "standing" on.

Ajax call to create sidebar with input fields:

```
var ajaxRequest = null;

$('.detailedTable tbody').on('click', '.tablerow', function() {
  var somedata = $(this).attr('data-somedata');

  ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
    url:"/ajax/showAccountSidebar",
    method:"GET",
    data: {
      somedata: somedata,
    },
    beforeSend:function() {
        if(ajaxRequest != null) {
            ajaxRequest.abort();
        }
     },
    success:function(data) {
      $('#sidemenu').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Ajax call to submit the input fields in sidebar:

```
var sidebarRequest = null;

$(document).on('click', '#sidebarMenu', function() {
  var someData = $("#someData").val();

  sidebarRequest = $.ajax({
    url:"/ajax/saveAccountNote",
    method:"POST",
    data: {
      inputData: someData
    },
    beforeSend:function() {
        if(sidebarRequest != null) {
            sidebarRequest.abort();
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: please show the HTML, we've only got half the picture here. We have no idea what input fields you're referring to, or what submit button(s) there are, or how they relate to the code. According to your code, an ajax request to "showAccountSideBar" should occur the moment the user clicks on any element within the table which has the "tablerow" class. Unless "tablerow" is actually representing a button, it's hard to see how this is related to any kind of  "submit" action. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I had was calling the second AJAX call with

```
$(document).on('click', '#sidebarMenu', function() {
```

Changed it to the following and now it only submits for the input fields I've clicked last:

```
$('#sidebarMenu').on('click', $(this), function() {
```

Comment: what is `this` in this context? Both here and in the question, the context in which this code runs is not clear. Have you by any chance got multiple elements with `id="sidebarMenu` in your HTML? Duplicate IDs are illegal in HTML - IDs must be unique, otherwise, tautologically, they're no longer an ID.

Comment: Hi! There will only be one element available at a time with the id "sidebarMenu". [this] in this context is the sidebar with the button that gets pressed. I changed the names from the actual ones to make it more clear but maybe it would be more clear if I named it "sidebarMenuButton" :)